# how to hide the entered password with ******* in batch programming?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a requirement like whenever we execute a test.bat file then it should ask enter password and entered password should be hidden with *****.
Is there any simplest way in batch programming for the above requirement?

I have written the below script using PowerShell is it fine/recommended to use PowerShell for this or any other simplest way is available?

```
@ECHO OFF 
setlocal
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter password:' -AsSecureString ; ^
   $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%G
echo "%password%"  
endlocal
```

Also suggest how to terminate the batch file as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not working?

Comment: I didn't know PowerShell was already available back in MS-DOS times...

Comment: So you are using PS to call a Batch? Why not do the Job completely in PS?

Comment: because this batch file will internally call the other batch file by passing password as parameter.

Comment: @Martin he isn't calling a Batch from Powershell, he's executing a powershell command from Batch I think.

Comment: Yes @DennisvanGils, Ive seen it. What i wanted to mention was a think-over to implement the whole process in PS if appropriate.

Comment: @Martin my requirement is for batch not for power shell is there any simplest way to mask password character using batch?? if yes then please suggest thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have to say, Good question.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this little example :

```
@echo off
Title %~n0 by Hackoo 2016
Mode 50,5 & Color 0E
:CreatePassword
cls & Color 0E
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Call :InputPassword "Please choose your password" pass1
Call :InputPassword "Please confirm your password" pass2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If !pass1!==!pass2! ( Goto:Good ) Else ( Goto:Bad )
::***********************************
:InputPassword
Cls
echo.
echo.
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
Goto :eof
::***********************************        
:Good
Color 0B                  
Cls
echo.
echo                     Good password
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo Your password stored as : "!Pass2!" without quotes
pause>nul
Goto :Eof
::***********************************
:Bad
Color 0C
Cls
echo.
echo             Wrong password try again
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo  Press any key to retry again
pause>nul
Goto :CreatePassword
::***********************************
```

And you can also give a try for this complete example **[Folder Loker.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320284/create-private-folder-with-cmd?answertab=active#tab-top)**

***Edit on 31/03/2016 @ 14:43***
**[Another way in pur batch based on replace command](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6382)**

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P "=Enter a Password:" < Nul
Call :PasswordInput
Echo(Your input was:!Line!
pause
Goto :Eof

:PasswordInput
::Author: Carlos Montiers Aguilera
::Last updated: 20150401. Created: 20150401.
::Set in variable Line a input password
For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'"Echo(|Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W"') Do Set "CR=%%#"
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt $H &For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%#"
Set "Line="
:_PasswordInput_Kbd
Set "CHR=" & For /F skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in (
'Replace.exe "%~f0" . /U /W') Do Set "CHR=%%#"
If !CHR!==!CR! Echo(&Goto :Eof
If !CHR!==!BS! (If Defined Line (Set /P "=!BS! !BS!" <Nul
Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
)
) Else (Set /P "=*" <Nul
If !CHR!==! (Set "Line=!Line!^!"
) Else Set "Line=!Line!!CHR!"
)
Goto :_PasswordInput_Kbd
```

And this is another version improved by ***aGerman***

```
@echo off & setlocal
Title %~n0
Mode 50,5 & Color 9E
Set /P "Pass1=Please choose your Password:" < Nul
call :HInput Pass1
echo Input length is %errorlevel%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Your password is !Pass1!
pause
cls
Set /P "Pass2=Please confirm your Password:" < Nul
call :HInput Pass2
echo Input length is %errorlevel%
echo Your password is !Pass2!
pause
cls
If !Pass1!==!Pass2! (echo the two passwords are the same
) else (echo the two passwords does not match)
pause
goto :eof


:HInput [ByRef_VarName]
:: inspired by Carlos
if "%__HI__%" neq "__HI__" (
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
  set "CR=" &set "S=" &set "N=0" &set "__HI__=__HI__"
  for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('echo(^|replace ? . /u /w') do if not defined CR set "CR=%%i"
  for /f %%i in ('"prompt $H &for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%i"
)
set "C="
for /f skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ('replace ? . /u /w') do if not defined C set "C=%%i"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
if "!CR!"=="!C!" (
  echo(
  if "%~1"=="" (
    echo(!S!
    endlocal &endlocal &exit /b %N%
  ) else (
    if defined S (
      for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &endlocal &set "%~1=%%i" &exit /b %N%
    ) else endlocal &endlocal &set "%~1=" &exit /b 0
  )
)
if "!BS!"=="!C!" (
  set "C="
  if defined S set /a "N -= 1" &set "S=!S:~,-1!" &<nul set /p "=%BS% %BS%"
) else set /a "N += 1" &<nul set /p "=*"
if not defined S (
  endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%C%"
) else for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%%i%C%"
goto HInput
```

Comment: You have used set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p in your code is there any other best way to mask the entered password any simplest way??

Comment: @Aryan Did you mean you want do it in pur batch and avoid using it with powershell ?? is it your aim ?

Comment: Yes exactly, or you can also recommend some easiest way using batch.

Comment: @Aryan Check my last edit !